# Template Specialization with Another Template with Something like "Using?"

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-specialization

I have a template definition. Something vaguely like the following:

```cpp
template<std::size_t ElemSize>
struct OptimizedArray;
```

For something like this, in order to optimize it, I may manually specialize it for sizes such as 1 byte, 2 bytes, and so on.
However, to support 3 bytes, I essentially have another template as follows, where it compiles two arrays of Size1 and Size2:

```cpp
template<size_t ElemSize1, size_t ElemSize2>
struct OptimizedDualArray;
```

In order to use the interface of OptimizedArray with 3 bytes, I would love to do something along the lines of the following:

```cpp
template<> 
using OptimizedArray<3> = OptimizedDualArray<1, 2>;
```

Directly, this does not work. However, is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: You might want to adjust it but the basic idea is to use class inheritance: `template <> struct OptimizedArray<3> : OptimizedDualArray<1,2> { using OptimizedDualArray::OptimizedDualArray; };`

Comment: `using` can be templated, but it can't be specialized.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a traits class that defines different member type aliases based on the value of `ElemSize`

```
template<std::size_t ElemSize>
struct OptimizedArray;

template<size_t ElemSize1, size_t ElemSize2>
struct OptimizedDualArray;

template<std::size_t ElemSize>
struct OptimizedArrayTraits {
  using type = OptimizedArray<ElemSize>;
};

template<>
struct OptimizedArrayTraits<3> {
  using type = OptimizedDualArray<1, 2>;
};

template<std::size_t ElemSize>
using OptimizedArrayType = 
  typename OptimizedArrayTraits<ElemSize>::type;
```

Then you can get the corresponding array type through `OptimizedArrayType<N>`.

Or directly use an immediately-invoked lambda to "specialize" `using` with different `ElemSize`

```
#include <type_traits> // for std::type_identity

template<std::size_t ElemSize>
using OptimizedArrayType = decltype([] {
  if constexpr (ElemSize == 3)
    return std::type_identity<OptimizedDualArray<1, 2>>{};
  else 
    return std::type_identity<OptimizedArray<ElemSize>>{};
}())::type;
```